# Can not find Java Runtime Environment Says ArgoUML

Tags: java, argouml

I have properly installed jdk in my system, I have also set the CLASSPATH properly, but when I am installing ArgoUML, it shows a Message the **No JRE found**, what should I do?

Comment: I installed [Windows x86 Offline](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html) as @Nithish said and it worked. Adding `JAVA_HOME7bin` on `PATH` wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've just had this problem too, with a properly installed x64 JRE 8u45.  Don't know if the Windows exe installer expects an x86 jvm?

Anyway, download the `binary package` zip instead from <del>[Tigris *(dead)*](http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/argouml-0.34/)</del> [GitHub Releases](https://github.com/argouml-tigris-org/argouml/releases/download/VERSION_0_35_1/ArgoUML-0.35.1.zip) and unzip somewhere. It runs fine from there * with `argouml.bat`, you just don't get a start menu entry added.

- EDIT: Your PATH must be correct to find the java.exe, easy way to check is to open a new Cmd shell (Start > Run... > cmd) and type `java -version` you should get something back from the jvm

Comment: Note : `java -version` is returning my JRE version but still not able to install AgroUML through the installer.

Answer (score 3):

Check if `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set (it should contain the directory your JRE is installed to).

Comment: Not true. `JAVA_HOME` should point to JDK directory, not JRE.

Comment: jdk already contains runtime engine therefore expect ArgoUML to support JDK if installed and path set correctly.

Comment: I tested JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK and JRE still not working.

Comment: same tested it by setting JAVA_HOME to my JDK install folder, still not working for ArgoUML install.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem on WIN7_X64.

I have installed it manually, here some steps:

- Download the [argouml-0.34 zip file](http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/argouml-0.34/)
- Extract the archive to install_dir Ex: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArgoUML-0.34` (to make it visible for all users)
- Create a shortcut `ArgoUML` in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` with the following information:

**Target:** "`install_dir\argouml.jar"` Ex: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArgoUML-0.34\argouml.jar"`

**Start in:** `"install_dir"` Ex: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArgoUML-0.34"`

**Change Icon...:** browse to `install_dir\ArgoUML.ico` Ex: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArgoUML-0.34\ArgoUML.ico`

> You ca use `argouml.bat` but the above steps are more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

I installed [windows x64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlhdm.png) first but it didn't work.

Then I installed [windows x86 offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N8Fj.png) and it worked.
Simple!

Answer (score 3):

First install 86 bit jre(Windows x86 Offline) from oracle.com then try to install ArgoUML.I think it will work.It has worked for me.Try to download from below given links for jre and ArgoUML.

jre link-

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html

ArgoUML link-

https://argouml.en.softonic.com/download

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use installer by first installing Java x86/32 bit JRE

Answer (score -1):

1. First install the jre-8u271-windows-x641.exe
2. Install argouml
3. Uninstall the jre-8u271-windows-x641.exe
4. Move to the folder: C: \ Users \ nameuser \ AppData \ Roaming \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Start Menu \ Programs \ ArgoUML right-click on ArgoUML then property under target: "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk-15 \ bin \ javaw.exe "-Xms64m -Xmx512m -jar" C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ArgoUML \ argouml.jar "specify the bin path of your jdk me mine is C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk- 15 \ bin \ javaw.exe
5. Execute the file (double click) .bat: C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ArgoUML \ argouml.bat